# How do you setup simple timer between two times when the other time is the next day?

Tags: python

Python noob here

```
from datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.time()

if now_time >= time(10,30) and now_time <= time(13,30):
    print "yes, within the interval"
```

I would like the timer to work between 10,30 AM today and 10 AM the next day. Changing time(13,30) to time(10,00) will not work, because I need to tell python 10,00 is the next day. I should use datetime function but don't know how. Any tips or examples appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using UNIX timestamps, which count the number of seconds?  just set a time that waits the appropriate number of seconds between tasks

Answer (score 1):

The `combine` method on the `datetime` class will help you a lot, as will the `timedelta` class. Here's how you would use them:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time

today = date.today()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)

interval_start = datetime.combine(today, time(10,30))
interval_end = datetime.combine(tomorrow, time(10,00))

time_to_check = datetime.now()  # Or any other datetime

if interval_start <= time_to_check <= interval_end:
    print "Within the interval"
```

Notice how I did the comparison. Python lets you "nest" comparisons like that, which is usually more succinct than writing `if start <= x and x <= end`.

P.S. Read https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html for more details about these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
today_10 = now.replace(hour=10, minute=30)
tomorrow_10 = (now + timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=10, minute=0)

if today_10 <= now <= tomorrow_10:
    print "yes, within the interval"
```

The logic is to create 3 `datetime` objects: one for today 10 AM, one for right now and one for tomorrow 10 AM. Them simply checking for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to creating time objects for the sake of comparison is to simply query the `hour` and `minute` attributes:

```
now= datetime.now().time()
if now.hour<10 or now.hour>10 or (now.hour==10 and now.minute>30):
    print('hooray')
```